# Jmeter Throughput shaping timer Questions

Tags: rest, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

So, I am using JMeter's throughput shaping timer to test the performance of our REST Server. I noticed a few things i did not expect.

First of all my setup details :

1)JMeter Version : 3.0 r1743807

2)JMX file : [DropBox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bw1w9bcx7w7b3fi/QAAS_Initiate.jmx?dl=0)

Now , my questions :

1)The throughput shaping timer is configured to run for 60 seconds(100rps - 30 secs, 200 rps - next 30 secs). But the actual test runs only for 3 seconds as shown below. Why?[image]

2) As per the plan the number of requests per second should go from 100 - 200. But here it seems to decrease , as in above.

3)As per [this plugin's documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) , the number of thread groups = desired requests per second * server response time / 1000 . Is it because how this plugin internally works  or is it a simple logic i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Thread Group settings.

[image]

You only one have 1 iteration and ramp up 300 users in 1 second. So if Jmeter can send all the 300 requests and get the response, JMeter will finish the test immediately. Those timer settings will apply only if the test is running.

If you need the test to run for some duration (say 60 seconds), then set the loop count to forever & duration to 60

Comment: Okay, so if i have only 300 users and they send only one request each - why does the txns per second graph start from 320? Also, if its just one iteration for which JMeter got all the responses ; why is there a decline line in the RPS graph? Shouldn't it ideally be just a point?

Comment: by the way, the forever trick helped and i got enough data now. Once you explain above questions , I will accept the answer :)